# Xamarin Forms - Android: framework activity doesn't include project resources

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm trying to use project specific Android drawables for a ToolbarItem. Because of the framework structure I use it appears as if my project specific drawables don't exist.

I created a project where I have the following structure:

[Project diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVZnj.png)

The Project.Android MainActivity inherits from a FrameworkMainActivity. The FrameworkMainActivity is responsible for calling the OnCreate method. The Xamarin.Forms.Application is acquired through an abstract method.

```
public abstract class FrameworkMainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        this.LoadApplication(this.GetApp());
    }


    protected abstract Xamarin.Forms.Application GetApp();
}
```

In the Framework.Xamarin.Forms project I have a MasterDetailPage that adds a demo toolbar item which uses an icon with source: 'demo.png'

```
public DemoMasterDetailPage()
{
    this.Master = new DemoMenuPage();
    this.Detail = new NavigationPage(new DemoContentPage());

    this.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem()
    {
        Icon = "demo.png",
        Text = "Demo",
    });
}
```

The ToolbarItem icon has to be project specific so I can't place it in my Framework. This is not possible because when I place my image in Project.Android > Resources > drawable folder the I get the following output:

```
[0:] Could not load image named: {0}: demo.png
```

When I place the image in the Framework.Android > Resources > drawable folder the ToolbarItem works perfectly and shows my icon correctly.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or how I can workaround the issue?

XF Version: 2.4.0.282

Comment: What's you mean "Framework.Android" and "Project.Android" ? "Framework.Android" is an Android library? Please elaborate a bit more.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT. Framework.Android is a Xamarin Android class library project. Project.Android is a deployable Xamarin Android project that depends on Framework.Android.